# Theme style for custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

My app has several themes from which the user can chose (red, blue, green etc.) Every theme has a corresponding button style (RedTheme => RedButton).
Now I have created a custom view which slightly extends "Button" and unfortunately this button does not get any style, except I use the "style" attribute in a layout.xml.
I don’t use any additional attributes, I just want that my Button style is applied.
I want to do something similar than:

```
 <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonmyTimeRed</item>
```

I have already read many other posts like this one:
[How to: Define theme (style) item for custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493947/how-to-define-theme-style-item-for-custom-widget)
but I’m not 100% sure if this solution fits for me since I don’t need any additional attributes.

Comment: What are you asking , can you be more clear

Comment: What is unclear for you? ->  I just want that my Theme Button Style is applied for my derived Button. I also described how I want to use it

Comment: have you seen the 3rd parameter in View constructor?

Comment: I just have 2 -> ClockButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: use 3 params ctor then

Comment: public ClockButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleRes) is not called

Comment: is not called? what do you mean?

Comment: I placed breakpoints in all of the three constructors and the one with two parameter is called

Comment: you should call it directly with your own custom defStyleAttr (last param of View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr))

Comment: How should I call it directly? It is definded in a layout.xml

Comment: see `LayoutInflater.Factory` interface

Comment: It seems that I found a verry verry simple solution. I had a look at android.widget.Button and I used the second constructor in my custom Button -> super(context, attrs, R.attr.buttonStyle);
I'm still testing but this seems to work

Comment: but you want use several styles. not just R.attr.buttonStyle, right?

Comment: R.attr.buttonStyle takes the styles for android.widget.Button which are defined in my custom Themes (not the default Android button styles). Thats exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Written article on [styling custom views in Android](http://onetouchcode.com/2016/11/25/styling-custom-views-android/).

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the three parameter super constructor and pass the button style resource id. This works for all my custom themes. Thanks @pskink for pointing me into right direction.

```
public ClockButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.attr.buttonStyle);
    ...
}
```

My theme looks like this:

```
<style name="LilaTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonmyTimeLila</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I get an error: failed to find style 'optionbuttoviewStyle'

optionbuttoviewStyle is a custom style found in my styles.xml