# apply custom theme to custom view android

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, themes

I'm trying to apply a theme to a CustomEditText which inherit directly from EditText like "android:theme" attribute would do to any other classic widget. 
My theme don't use a style with custom attribute, it overloads my apptheme attributes to have a different "ColorControlNormal" attribute for exemple. 
Here are my theme :

Apptheme :

```
 <style name="Theme.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/grey_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

The theme I want to apply to my CustomEditText :

```
<style name="CustomEditTextTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_medium</item>
    <item name="android:ems">8</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey_medium</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey_medium</item>
</style>
```

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493947/how-to-define-theme-style-item-for-custom-widget/5052401#5052401) but I don't have custom style attributes and I can't apply "CustomEditTextTheme" to my whole activity.

Obviously, `android:theme="@style/CustomEditText` don't make the job.

Comment: are you looking for style="@style/CustomEditText" ?

Comment: No, It wouldn't work even with normal widgets since I define "colorControl.." which are theme properties. What I'm trying to do is to apply CustomEditTextTheme to my CustomEditText like "android:theme" does on non-custom widgets.