# Get material design colors at runtime outside the scope

Tags: android

I´m trying to outsource my custom view into an own library.

Is it possible to get the colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent attributes outside the scope, maybe at runtime?

**Solution**
I´ve pointed it out myself.

In xml use:

```
?attr/attributeName
```

f.e.

```
?attr/colorAccent
```

In code use sth like:

```
public int getColorValueByAttr(Context context, int attrResId) {
    int color = 0;

    TypedArray a = null;
    try {
        int[] attrs = {attrResId};
        a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
        color = a.getColor(0, 0);
    } finally {
        if (a != null) {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Yes, by accessing the theme colors

Comment: @DavidMedenjak can you give me an example on how to access f.e. colorAccent in code and xml?

Comment: Use e.g. `context.obtainStyledAttributes`, there are lots of questions on this, e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493947/how-to-define-theme-style-item-for-custom-widget