# Add custom widget styling to app theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I've implemented a custom view with custom attributes and I am trying to style it in the theme. I've followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052401/1969198), but my widget is not picking up the style from the app theme.

The custom attributes for my widget:

```
<declare-styleable name="BarGraph">
    <attr name="barColour" format="color"/>
    <attr name="barWidth" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="maxBarHeight" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="barWhiteSpace" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Declare the style reference:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTheme">
    <attr name="barGraphStyle" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Style my widget:

```
<style name="AppTheme.BarGraphStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="barColour">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="barWidth">@dimen/bar_graph_bar_width</item>
    <item name="maxBarHeight">@dimen/bar_graph_bar_max_height</item>
    <item name="barWhiteSpace">@dimen/bar_white_space</item>
</style>
```

Add the style to my app's theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="barGraphStyle">@style/AppTheme.BarGraphStyle</item>
</style>
```

Finally, I get the custom attributes in my custom component's constructor:

```
TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BarGraph);
ColorStateList barColour = styledAttributes.getColorStateList(R.styleable.BarGraph_barColour);
Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: barColour = " + barColour);

float barWidth = styledAttributes.getDimension(R.styleable.BarGraph_barWidth, -1);
float maxHeight = styledAttributes.getDimension(R.styleable.BarGraph_maxBarHeight, -1);
float barWhiteSpace = styledAttributes
            .getDimension(R.styleable.BarGraph_barWhiteSpace, -1);
    styledAttributes.recycle();
Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: barWidth = " + barWidth);
Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: maxHeight = " + maxHeight);
Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: barWhiteSpace = " + barWhiteSpace);
```

Log output from the constructor:

```
D/BarGraph( 6862): BarGraph: barColour = null
D/BarGraph( 6862): BarGraph: barWidth = -1.0
D/BarGraph( 6862): BarGraph: maxHeight = -1.0 
D/BarGraph( 6862): BarGraph: barWhiteSpace = -1.0
```

If I apply the style directly on my widget, using `style="@style/AppTheme.BarGraphStyle"`, it styles correctly, so I know it's not a problem with the style itself.

**Edit:** my constructors:

```
public BarGraph(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public BarGraph(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // grab all the custom styling values
    TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BarGraph);
    ColorStateList barColour = styledAttributes.getColorStateList(R.styleable.BarGraph_barColour);
    Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: barColour = " + barColour);

    float barWidth = styledAttributes.getDimension(R.styleable.BarGraph_barWidth, -1);
    float maxHeight = styledAttributes.getDimension(R.styleable.BarGraph_maxBarHeight, -1);
    float barWhiteSpace = styledAttributes .getDimension(R.styleable.BarGraph_barWhiteSpace, -1);
    styledAttributes.recycle();

    Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: barWidth = " + barWidth);
    Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: maxHeight = " + maxHeight);
    Log.d(TAG, "BarGraph: barWhiteSpace = " + barWhiteSpace);

    // other non-styling code...
}
```

Comment: Can u plz post all constructors of your custom component?

Comment: @AndreClassen added them

Comment: `AppTheme.BarGraphStyle` is not supposed to inherit from a whole theme. `""` or `"android:Widget"` would be great parents. While at it change the name to better reflect that it's a *style* and not a *theme*. `Widget.BarGraph` would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors should be like this:

```
    public BarGraph(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.barGraphStyle);
    }

    public BarGraph(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // grab all the custom styling values
        TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes( attrs, R.styleable.BarGraph, defStyle, 0);

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Won't that just use the default, though?

Comment: @AesSedai101 What are you worry about? `R.attr.barGraphStyle` refers the style defined in `AppTheme`. There is problems?

Answer (score 2):

Change your second constructor like this,

```
public BarGraph(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.barGraphStyle);
    }
```

And inside your third constructor, use this line

```
    TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BarGraph, defStyleAttr, R.style.AppTheme_BarGraphStyle);
```

You have missed these lines. It's working perfectly for me with this code.

Comment: `BarGraph(Context, AttributeSet)` is the contructor invoked while inflating from XML. `R.attr.barGraphStyle` is the (optional) theme attribute pointing to a style. `R.style.AppTheme_BarGraphStyle` is a style containing default values. Values from this default style will always be picked unless they're overridden by the `barGraphsStyle` theme attribute or `style` attribute or direct attributes.