# Access resource array members by name

Tags: android, arrays, android-resources

Suppose this sample definition in `res/values/a_file.xml`:

```
<array name="theme0">
    <item name="widgetBackground">@color/widget_background0</item>
    <item name="widgetGlowColor">@color/widget_glowColor0</item>
    <!-- etc -->
</array>
```

And this code in `java`:

```
int[] arr = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.theme0);
```

Now you can easily access to its members: `arr[0], arr[1], ...`

---

But I want to access its members **by their names**. Something like:

```
arr.getMemeber("widgetBackground")
arr.getMemeber("widgetGlowColor")
...
```

Or everything *by name, not by number*. Is it possible?

Comment: better you use custom attributes for this purpose. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#applyattr

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/a/5052401/5923606