# how to select a specific inflated textView and set style to it via code?

Tags: android, layout, styles, themes, android-custom-view

I have a CustomViewGroup with few textViews.

I want to create a themes "big" and "small" to change the first text size and margins.

How can i do this? as i have found 3 posts about themes and styles, but i think it's not possible when i have to set the style for just one textView (how do i select it specifically?)

1) I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime)

but wasn't sure if that's a usable syntax:

`style="?textBody"`

plus is it possible to `setTheme` to just current context? (In my current customView)

2) I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052401/311130)

but I don't understand how does each attribute linked to a specific view (say i have two text views and i want to change the style of just one of them)

or does that mean that any button will get this attribute?

```
<style name="Widget.ImageButton.Custom" parent="android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
```

3) I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043373/311130) which i undrestand you can set style only views only when creating them via code (not xml)

Comment: How is your CustomViewGroup created? Are both the parent and child views defined in the same XML file (e.g. `<CustomViewGroup><TextView/><TextView/></CustomViewGroup>`) or are you inflating them in the constructor of CustomViewGroup? Or something else entirely?

Comment: both the parent and child views defined in the same XML file