# Custom views and defStyleAttr

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, declare-styleable

I'm struggling with custom views `defStyleAttr`. (Short note I'm using a `Preference` as example cause it's the same way Google uses it)

So for almost every `View` or `Preference` that is provided by Android you'll have a constructor like [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/src/main/java/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference.java):

```java
public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.seekBarPreferenceStyle);
}
```

This defines the default style attribute to be `R.attr.seekBarPreferenceStyle`.

If you now look into the [definition](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/res/values/attrs.xml) you'll find this:

```xml
<attr name="seekBarPreferenceStyle" format="reference" />
```

Until now everything is clear. But this attribute is somehow linked to a [theme](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/res/values/themes.xml):

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
        <!-- ... -->
        <item name="seekBarPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.SeekBarPreference.Material</item>
        <!-- ... -->
    </style>
    <!-- ... -->
</resources>
```

Which then finally links a [style](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/res/values/styles.xml) with the needed layout resource id that will be handed over to the super class to be inflated:

```xml
<style name="Preference.SeekBarPreference.Material">
        <item name="android:layout">@layout/preference_widget_seekbar_material</item>
        <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a hint on how the theme `PreferenceThemeOverlay` is linked to the attribute `seekBarPreferenceStyle`.

So how are these two linked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052401/5437331) that explained the basics you need to know.

## Custom View

For the examples I use `SeekBarPreference` as a custom object (`Preference` and `View` are very similar)

So in short there are two ways to set your default style.

Either set a custom theme to your activity (or the like) that links something to your custom style (`seekBarPreferenceStyle`) or set the style directly by the `style` XML attribute.

#### Theme

styles.xml

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="seekBarPreferenceStyle">@style/LINK_TO_DEFINING_STYLE</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

#### Style attribute

some.xml

```xml
<SeekBarPreference
[...]
style="@style/LINK_TO_DEFINING_STYLE"
[...] />
```

## Androids Way

But I wanted to know exactly how all of it is connected to then work without any `style` attributes in XML files for `SeekBarPreference` or other `Preference` and `View` objects provided by Android.

So (via Android Studio) I followed `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` down to its parent [`Theme.Holo.Light`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes_holo.xml) and look what I found there:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<item name="seekBarPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.Holo.SeekBarPreference</item>
<!-- ... -->
```

Linking to [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) style which links the layout resource:

```xml
<style name="Preference.Holo.SeekBarPreference">
    <item name="layout">@layout/preference_widget_seekbar</item>
</style>
```

And to finally bring some more confusion to you again, Android seems to link a the Material style from the question instead of the Holo theme from the answer to the default theme (be it `DeviceDefault` or something else).

So if you got any clue on this please feel free to add to the comments :)